# Can't draw compatible target bitmap as effect to this compatible target

Tags: c++, direct2d

I want is to create backdrop-blur effect as in UWP apps in-app blur for my ui library, but I've been stuck with it for a few days.

For some reason, it either does not set backbuffer bitmap in SetInput method correctly, or in DrawImage call. The saddest thing is that backbuffer bitmap is actually valid, it could be drawn by same DrawImage call. Maybe I should specify another bitmap options when create it?

My current code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

HDC hdcDevice = GetDC(NULL);
int xw = GetDeviceCaps(hdcDevice, HORZRES);
int yw = GetDeviceCaps(hdcDevice, VERTRES);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

HWND hwnd;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")

template<class Interface>
inline void SafeRelease(
    Interface** ppInterfaceToRelease)
{
    if (*ppInterfaceToRelease != NULL)
    {
        (*ppInterfaceToRelease)->Release();
        (*ppInterfaceToRelease) = NULL;
    }
}

#ifndef Assert
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
#define Assert(b) do {if (!(b)) {OutputDebugStringA("Assert: " #b "\n");}} while(0)
#else
#define Assert(b)
#endif //DEBUG || _DEBUG
#endif

#ifndef HINST_THISCOMPONENT
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#define HINST_THISCOMPONENT ((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase)
#endif

ID2D1Factory* m_pDirect2dFactory;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* m_pRenderTarget;
ID2D1DeviceContext* target;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush* brush;

void Release()
{
      SafeRelease(&m_pRenderTarget);
      SafeRelease(&target);
      SafeRelease(&brush);
}

void Init()
{
Release();
m_pRenderTarget = NULL;


RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(
rc.right - rc.left,
rc.bottom - rc.top);

// Create a Direct2D render target.
SUCCEEDED(m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size),
&m_pRenderTarget));

m_pRenderTarget->QueryInterface(&target);
}


inline void Blur(ID2D1DeviceContext* backTarget, int rad, RECT r)
// r is not used, should contain element bound box in future,
// so backtarget->DrawImage will only draw part that 
// belongs to element's area
{
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(
rc.right - rc.left,
rc.bottom - rc.top);

// Draw rectangle for test
backTarget->FillRectangle(D2D1::RectF(30, 30, 100, 100), brush);

ID2D1Bitmap1* bb = nullptr;

// Create bitmap
backTarget->CreateBitmap(size, 0, 0, D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET,
D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
), &bb);

// Copy current taget's state to created bitmap
bb->CopyFromRenderTarget(0, backTarget, 0);


ID2D1Effect* blur = nullptr;
target->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1GaussianBlur, &blur);
blur->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION, 10);
blur->SetInput(0, bb);

// Draw blurred result. Does nothing
backTarget->DrawImage(blur);

// Just test if bb is valid, draw
// it with some offset. 
// Draws correctly
auto a = D2D1::Point2F(100, 0);
backTarget->DrawImage(bb, a);

SafeRelease(&blur);
}

inline void Render()
{
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(
rc.right - rc.left,
rc.bottom - rc.top);

ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget* tar = nullptr; // Create back buffer
target->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(&tar);

ID2D1DeviceContext* tt = nullptr; 
// Get exactly back buffer as ID2D1DeviceContext*, 
// because it has more draw call, such as DrawImage()
tar->QueryInterface(&tt);
tt->CreateSolidColorBrush(
D2D1::ColorF(255, 0, 0),
&brush
);


tt->BeginDraw();
tt->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Blue));
tt->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

// for(int i = 0; i < ui_elements_count; i++)
// {
//     ui_element->DrawBlurredAreaBehindIt(tt);
//     ui_element->DrawInnerText(tt);
//     ui_element->DrawBorder(tt);
//     ui_element->DrawSomethingElse(tt);
// }
// loop through ui elements should be here, 
// assume we have an element with blur needed
Blur(tt, 10, RECT());

tt->EndDraw();

target->BeginDraw();

ID2D1Bitmap* bmp = nullptr;
tar->GetBitmap(&bmp);

target->DrawImage(bmp);

SafeRelease(&tar);
SafeRelease(&tt);
SafeRelease(&bmp);
SafeRelease(&brush);

target->EndDraw();
}



int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hin, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcDevice);

WNDCLASS c = { NULL };
c.lpszClassName = L"asd";
c.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
c.hInstance = hin;
c.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
c.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
c.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
RegisterClass(&c);

int cx = 500, cy = 500;
int x = xw / 2 - cx / 2, y = yw / 2 - cy / 2;

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"asd", L"asd", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, cx, cy, NULL, NULL, hin, 0);

HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);
CoInitialize(NULL);

SUCCEEDED(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &m_pDirect2dFactory));

Init();

MSG msg;

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
Render();
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

CoUninitialize();

return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
switch (message)
{
default:
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wp, lp);
}
return NULL;
}
```

To obtain current drawing bitmap `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget*` need to be created as backbuffer. But, this interface does not have all draw methods suchs as `DrawImage`, or `CreateEffect`, so I have tried to `QueryInterface` `ID2D1DeviceContext` from it, and it actually works.

For getting backbuffer bitmap I use `ID2D1Bitmap::CopyFromRenderTarget` because if to draw bitmap from `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget::GetBitmap` it will draw just nothing.

**Important update**

I just changed blur effect to scale effect, and fortunately or unfortunately, with scale effect it works. Please, don't tell it is a direct2d bug, I sure I doing here something wrong.

[image: After scale]

I noticed that in all examples this effect created and initialized by `SetInput` and `SetValue` calls **before** the render loop, out of `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw`. Maybe after that calls the image is somehow prepared asynchronously, so it just does not have time be ready to be drawn being in render loop? But it sounds crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You will not believe. YOU WILL NOT BELIEVE.

The problem was that, the the `D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION` value in `blur->SetValue` call was in `int`, and should in `float`. And it is not regular reverse case when You trying to pass 0.5 to some `int` value and it casted to 1. Just think about this stupidnes.

That's not a joke,

```
blur->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION, 3.0f); // works

blur->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION, 3); // does not work
```

What? Why? Because of what? - I don't know answer to these questions as You, seems like that's just how things work.

[image]

---

And yes, on MSDN it [is written](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/gaussian-blur) that `D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION` type is `FLOAT`, but how? How `10` can not work, but `10.0f` works?

Comment: Because 10 is not a float (!). This happens because you're implicitly using a C++ template overload, not the real COM method: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1properties-setvalue(uint32_d2d1_property_type_constbyte_uint32). These overloads use D2D1_PROPERTY_TYPE_UNKNOWN which means 10 will be raw cast into a float (1.401e-44) so it "works" with 1.401e-44 as stddev, and gives a black screen. But `int ui = 10; auto hr = blur->SetValue(D2D1_GAUSSIANBLUR_PROP_STANDARD_DEVIATION, D2D1_PROPERTY_TYPE_UINT32, (BYTE*)&ui, 4)` gets hr = E_INVALIDARG as expected

Comment: @SimonMourier, yeah I also have been wondering that it is because of template as an argument. Few wasted days and so damn error...